# Add users to AWS elasticsearch kibana dashboard through API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to map users to kibana roles, however, when I do a GET request on _plugins/_security
I get a 401 error. I'm trying to do this from Kibana dashboard where I have all_access
role as well as from an Ec2 instance where the machine role is mapped to all_access
role. Need help in understanding how can I fix the same.

```
{"Message":"Your request: '/_plugins/_security' is not allowed."}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to ask aws about this, as they run a fork of Elasticsearch that doesn't contain this particular functionality

Answer (score 0):

On our version of AWS ES, I have to do this prefix in order to access the security API:

GET _opendistro/_security/api/roles

What you have to understand is the AWS ES does not use the "normal" ElasticSearch, it uses the OpenDistro version, therefor some commands are different.

Here is the link to the API doc for security :
https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security/access-control/api/#access-control-for-the-api